# issue with output of json file caused by blank in the javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to get some data out of a json file. The issue I have in the output there is a blank in the column header. I already tried to replace the blenk with a "_" but this did not help. When I simply name it as it is I am getting the error:
SyntaxError: Expected token '}' file:

Can you tell me how I need to manipulate the script to get the Data?

```
{
            tableData.push({
                "id" : id_temp,
                "datetime": feat[j].datetime,
                "Percent_Available_Memory": feat[j].Percent Available Memory,
                "Available_Memory": feat[j].Available_Memory,
                "Total_Memory": feat[j].Total Memory,
                "coverage": feat[j].coverage

            });
        }
```

Comment: So you want to write tableData as json?

Answer (score 1):

OK, try this:

```
"Percent_Available_Memory": feat[j]["Percent Available Memory"],
```

...

```
"Total_Memory": feat[j]["Total Memory"],
```

Comment: Perfect, this is working. Thanks in advance